# Background image - constrain proportions

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a div with background-image. Div has width od 20% - I want it change its size depending on user resolution. The problem is that I cannot force the background image to scale constraining proportions. 
Moreover, I have a label - I want i to be placed at the bottom of the first div.

Here is what I want to accomplish:

[image]

My code:

```
 <a href="">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="label">Beijing</div>
            <div class="description">August 2014</div>
        </div>
    </a>
```

My CSS:

```
.box {
    float: left;
    width: 19.60%;
    margin-left:0.40%;
    margin-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
    background-image: url("beijing.png");
    background-size: cover;
}

.label {
    font-size:28px;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:Roboto;
    font-weight:300;
    background-color: rgba(60, 60, 62, 0.5);
}

.description {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:Roboto;
    font-weight:300;
    background-color: rgba(60, 60, 62, 0.5);
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at your code, and it seems that you have not specified a height for `.box` — so this causes the content to collapse to the height of the content, obscuring the background image completely.

What I can suggest is that you use a combination of the [padding bottom hack to dictate a fixed aspect ratio](https://css-tricks.com/easier-aspect-ratio-elements/) of your `.box` element, as well as wrap the meta data (label and location) within another element, which is then positioned absolutely within the box.

```css
.box {
  float: left;
  width: 19.60%;
  margin-left:0.40%;
  margin-top:10px;
  text-align:center;
  background-image: url("https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1426200830301-372615e4ac54");
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 19.60%;
}
.meta {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.label {
  font-size:28px;
  color:#fff;
  font-family:Roboto;
  font-weight:300;
  background-color: rgba(60, 60, 62, 0.5);
}

.description {
  font-size:12px;
  color:#fff;
  font-family:Roboto;
  font-weight:300;
  background-color: rgba(60, 60, 62, 0.5);
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

```html
<a href="">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="meta">
      <div class="label">Beijing</div>
      <div class="description">August 2014</div>
      </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

---

**Even better:** I know that this is probably not what you're looking for, but instead of using percentages to dictate margins and then carefully subtracting that from the fractional width, what you can do is simply use CSS flexbox or CSS columns to do the heavy lifting (depending on which direction you want your elements to flow).

Also, it might be too laborious to use CSS to individually specify the background image for each `.box` element. You can store the background image as a HTML5 `data-` attribute value, and then use JS (in this case I will use jQuery to make the code more readable, but a raw JS approach is totally feasible) to assigned the background images iteratively.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.box').each(function() {
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url('+$(this).data('bg')+')');
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 5px;
}
.box {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  width: calc(20% - 10px);
  padding-bottom: 19.60%;
  text-align:center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
.meta {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.label {
  font-size:28px;
  color:#fff;
  font-family:Roboto;
  font-weight:300;
  background-color: rgba(60, 60, 62, 0.5);
}

.description {
  font-size:12px;
  color:#fff;
  font-family:Roboto;
  font-weight:300;
  background-color: rgba(60, 60, 62, 0.5);
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="" class="box" data-bg="https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1426200830301-372615e4ac54">
    <div class="meta">
      <div class="label">Beijing</div>
      <div class="description">August 2014</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="box" data-bg="https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1423683249427-8ca22bd873e0">
    <div class="meta">
      <div class="label">Beijing</div>
      <div class="description">August 2014</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="box" data-bg="https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1421091242698-34f6ad7fc088">
    <div class="meta">
      <div class="label">Beijing</div>
      <div class="description">August 2014</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="box" data-bg="https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1421809313281-48f03fa45e9f">
    <div class="meta">
      <div class="label">Beijing</div>
      <div class="description">August 2014</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="box" data-bg="https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1421757295538-9c80958e75b0">
    <div class="meta">
      <div class="label">Beijing</div>
      <div class="description">August 2014</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="box" data-bg="https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1421940975339-33bdde74a873">
    <div class="meta">
      <div class="label">Beijing</div>
      <div class="description">August 2014</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="box" data-bg="https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1421977870504-378093748ae6">
    <div class="meta">
      <div class="label">Beijing</div>
      <div class="description">August 2014</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="box" data-bg="https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1421930451953-73c5c9ae9abf">
    <div class="meta">
      <div class="label">Beijing</div>
      <div class="description">August 2014</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="box" data-bg="https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1422310299561-e3b8b45d859f">
    <div class="meta">
      <div class="label">Beijing</div>
      <div class="description">August 2014</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="box" data-bg="https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1423483641154-5411ec9c0ddf">
    <div class="meta">
      <div class="label">Beijing</div>
      <div class="description">August 2014</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Image courtesy of https://unsplash.com/.